# '' dpkg -l '' shows the list begin with p but not any previous alphabet

Tags: dpkg

when i use this command '' dpkg -l '' output of terminal is like bellow

```
ii  python-gobject 2.28.6-12bui amd64        deprecated static Python bindings
ii  python-gst0.10 0.10.22-3ubu amd64        generic media-playing framework (
ii  python-gtk2    2.24.0-3ubun amd64        Python bindings for the GTK+ widg
ii  python-httplib 0.8-2build1  all          comprehensive HTTP client library
ii  python-ibus    1.5.5-1ubunt all          Intelligent Input Bus - Python su
ii  python-imaging 2.3.0-1ubunt all          Python Imaging Library compatibil
ii  python-imaging 2.3.0-1ubunt all          Dummy transitional package
ii  python-keyring 3.5-1        all          store and access your passwords s
ii  python-launchp 1.10.2+ds-2  all          Launchpad web services client lib
ii  python-lazr.re 0.13.3-1buil all          client for lazr.restful-based web
ii  python-lazr.ur 1.0.3-1build all          library for parsing, manipulating
ii  python-ldb     1:1.1.16-1   amd64        Python bindings for LDB
ii  python-libxml2 2.9.1+dfsg1- amd64        Python bindings for the GNOME XML
ii  python-lockfil 1:0.8-2ubunt all          file locking library for Python
ii  python-lxml    3.3.3-1ubunt amd64        pythonic binding for the libxml2 
ii  python-mako    0.9.1-1      all          fast and lightweight templating f
ii  python-markups 0.18-1build2 amd64        HTML/XHTML/XML string library for
ii  python-matplot 1.3.1-1ubunt amd64        Python based plotting system in a
ii  python-matplot 1.3.1-1ubunt all          Python based plotting system (dat
ii  python-minimal 2.7.5-5ubunt amd64        minimal subset of the Python lang
ii  python-mlt     0.9.0-3      amd64        multimedia framework (python bind
ii  python-notify  0.1.1-3ubunt amd64        Python bindings for libnotify
ii  python-ntdb    1.0-2ubuntu1 amd64        Python bindings for NTDB
ii  python-numpy   1:1.8.2-0ubu amd64        Numerical Python adds a fast arra
ii  python-oauth   1.0.1-3build all          Python library implementing of th
ii  python-oauthli 0.6.1-1      all          generic, spec-compliant implement
ii  python-oneconf 0.3.7        all          synchronize your configuration da
ii  python-opengl  3.0.2-1      all          Python bindings to OpenGL (Python
ii  python-openssl 0.13-2ubuntu amd64        Python 2 wrapper around the OpenS
ii  python-pam     0.4.2-13.1ub amd64        Python interface to the PAM libra
ii  python-pexpect 3.1-1ubuntu0 all          Python module for automating inte
ii  python-pil     2.3.0-1ubunt amd64        Python Imaging Library (Pillow fo
ii  python-piston- 0.7.5-0ubunt all          library for writing clients for D
ii  python-pkg-res 3.3-1ubuntu1 all          Package Discovery and Resource Ac
ii  python-poppler 0.12.1-8.1   amd64        Poppler Python bindings
ii  python-problem 2.14.1-0ubun all          Python library to handle problem 
ii  python-protobu 2.5.0-9ubunt all          Python bindings for protocol buff
ii  python-pycurl  7.19.3-0ubun amd64        Python bindings to libcurl
ii  python-pygooca 0.14.1-1ubun amd64        GooCanvas Python bindings
ii  python-pyinoti 0.9.4-1build all          simple Linux inotify Python bindi
ii  python-pyparsi 2.0.1+dfsg1- all          Python parsing module
ii  python-pypdf   1.13-1       all          PDF toolkit implemented solely in
ii  python-qt4     4.10.4+dfsg- amd64        Python bindings for Qt4
ii  python-qt4-dbu 4.10.4+dfsg- amd64        D-Bus Support for PyQt4
ii  python-qwt5-qt 5.2.1~cvs200 amd64        Python version of the Qwt5 techni
ii  python-renderp 3.0-1build1  amd64        python low level render interface
ii  python-reportl 3.0-1build1  all          ReportLab library to create PDF d
ii  python-reportl 3.0-1build1  amd64        C coded extension accelerator for
ii  python-samba   2:4.1.6+dfsg amd64        Python bindings for Samba
ii  python-scipy   0.13.3-1buil amd64        scientific tools for Python
ii  python-secrets 2.0.0-1ubunt all          Python module for storing secrets
ii  python-serial  2.6-1build1  all          pyserial - module encapsulating a
ii  python-simplej 3.3.1-1ubunt amd64        simple, fast, extensible JSON enc
ii  python-sip     4.15.5-1buil amd64        Python/C++ bindings generator run
ii  python-sip-dev 4.15.5-1buil amd64        Python/C++ bindings generator dev
ii  python-six     1.5.2-1      all          Python 2 and 3 compatibility libr
ii  python-smbc    1.0.14.1-0ub amd64        Python bindings for Samba clients
ii  python-support 1.0.15       all          automated rebuilding support for 
ii  python-talloc  2.1.0-1      amd64        hierarchical pool based memory al
ii  python-tdb     1.2.12-1     amd64        Python bindings for TDB
ii  python-tk      2.7.5-1ubunt amd64        Tkinter - Writing Tk applications
ii  python-twisted 13.2.0-1ubun amd64        Event-based framework for interne
ii  python-twisted 13.2.0-1ubun all          Event-based framework for interne
ii  python-twisted 13.2.0-1ubun all          DNS protocol implementation with 
ii  python-twisted 13.2.0-1ubun all          HTTP protocol implementation toge
ii  python-tz      2012c-1build all          Python version of the Olson timez
ii  python-ubuntu- 13.10-0ubunt all          Ubuntu Single Sign-On client - Py
rc  python-ubuntuo 13.10-0ubunt all          Ubuntu One client Python librarie
ii  python-vte     1:0.28.2-5ub amd64        Python bindings for the VTE widge
ii  python-wadllib 1.3.2-2build all          Python library for navigating WAD
ii  python-wxgtk2. 2.8.12.1+dfs amd64        wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI 
ii  python-wxversi 2.8.12.1+dfs all          wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI 
ii  python-xapian  1.2.16-2ubun amd64        Xapian search engine interface fo
ii  python-xdg     0.25-4       all          Python 2 library to access freede
ii  python-zeitgei 0.9.14-0ubun all          event logging framework - Python 
ii  python-zope.in 4.0.5-1ubunt amd64        Interfaces for Python
ii  python2.7      2.7.6-8      amd64        Interactive high-level object-ori
ii  python2.7-dev  2.7.6-8      amd64        Header files and a static library
ii  python2.7-mini 2.7.6-8      amd64        Minimal subset of the Python lang
ii  python3        3.4.0-0ubunt amd64        interactive high-level object-ori
ii  python3-apparm 2.8.95~2430- amd64        AppArmor Python3 utility library
ii  python3-apport 2.14.1-0ubun all          Python 3 library for Apport crash
ii  python3-apt    0.9.3.5      amd64        Python 3 interface to libapt-pkg
ii  python3-aptdae 1.1.1-1ubunt all          Python 3 module for the server an
ii  python3-aptdae 1.1.1-1ubunt all          Python 3 GTK+ 3 widgets to run an
ii  python3-aptdae 1.1.1-1ubunt all          PackageKit compatibilty for AptDa
ii  python3-brlapi 5.0-2ubuntu2 amd64        Braille display access via BRLTTY
ii  python3-cairo  1.10.0+dfsg- amd64        Python 3 bindings for the Cairo v
ii  python3-charde 2.0.1-1      all          universal encoding detector
ii  python3-checkb 0.17.6-0ubun all          CheckBox python3 library
ii  python3-checkb 0.3-2        all          PlainBox based test runner (Pytho
ii  python3-checkb 0.2-1        all          collection of Python modules used
ii  python3-comman 0.3ubuntu12  all          Python 3 bindings for command-not
ii  python3-crypto 2.6.1-4build amd64        cryptographic algorithms and prot
ii  python3-dbus   1.2.0-2build amd64        simple interprocess messaging sys
ii  python3-debian 0.1.21+nmu2u all          Python 3 modules to work with Deb
ii  python3-defer  1.0.6-2build all          Small framework for asynchronous 
ii  python3-dirspe 13.10-0ubunt all          Python User Folders Specification
ii  python3-distup 1:0.220.5    all          manage release upgrades
ii  python3-feedpa 5.1.3-2      all          Universal Feed Parser for Python 
ii  python3-gdbm:a 3.4.0-0ubunt amd64        GNU dbm database support for Pyth
ii  python3-gi     3.12.0-1ubun amd64        Python 3 bindings for gobject-int
ii  python3-gi-cai 3.12.0-1ubun amd64        Python 3 Cairo bindings for the G
ii  python3-httpli 0.8-2build1  all          comprehensive HTTP client library
ii  python3-libapp 2.8.95~2430- amd64        AppArmor library Python3 bindings
ii  python3-louis  2.5.3-2ubunt all          Python bindings for liblouis
ii  python3-lxml   3.3.3-1ubunt amd64        pythonic binding for the libxml2 
ii  python3-mako   0.9.1-1      all          fast and lightweight templating f
ii  python3-markup 0.18-1build2 amd64        HTML/XHTML/XML string library for
ii  python3-minima 3.4.0-0ubunt amd64        minimal subset of the Python lang
ii  python3-oauthl 0.6.1-1      all          generic, spec-compliant implement
ii  python3-onecon 0.3.7        all          synchronize your configuration da
ii  python3-piston 0.7.5-0ubunt all          library for writing clients for D
ii  python3-pkg-re 3.3-1ubuntu1 all          Package Discovery and Resource Ac
ii  python3-plainb 0.5.3-2      all          toolkit for software and hardware
ii  python3-proble 2.14.1-0ubun all          Python 3 library to handle proble
ii  python3-pyatsp 2.10.0+dfsg- all          Assistive Technology Service Prov
ii  python3-pycurl 7.19.3-0ubun amd64        Python 3 bindings to libcurl
ii  python3-pypars 2.0.1+dfsg1- all          Python parsing module, Python3 pa
ii  python3-reques 2.2.1-1ubunt all          elegant and simple HTTP library f
ii  python3-six    1.5.2-1      all          Python 2 and 3 compatibility libr
ii  python3-softwa 0.92.37.2    all          manage the repositories that you 
ii  python3-speech 0.8-5ubuntu1 all          Python interface to Speech Dispat
ii  python3-uno    1:4.2.7-0ubu amd64        Python-UNO bridge
ii  python3-update 1:0.196.12   all          python 3.x module for update-mana
ii  python3-urllib 1.7.1-1build all          HTTP library with thread-safe con
ii  python3-xdg    0.25-4       all          Python 3 library to access freede
ii  python3-xkit   0.5.0ubuntu2 all          library for the manipulation of x
rc  python3.3      3.3.2-7ubunt amd64        Interactive high-level object-ori
rc  python3.3-mini 3.3.2-7ubunt amd64        Minimal subset of the Python lang
ii  python3.4      3.4.0-2ubunt amd64        Interactive high-level object-ori
ii  python3.4-mini 3.4.0-2ubunt amd64        Minimal subset of the Python lang
ii  qapt-batch     2.1.70-0ubun amd64        Batch package manager for KDE
ii  qdbus          4:4.8.5+git1 amd64        Qt 4 D-Bus tool
ii  qpdf           5.1.1-1      amd64        tools for and transforming and in
ii  qt-at-spi:amd6 0.3.1-4fakes amd64        at-spi accessibility plugin for Q
ii  qt4-default    4:4.8.5+git1 amd64        Qt 4 development defaults package
ii  qt4-designer   4:4.8.5+git1 amd64        graphical designer for Qt 4 appli
ii  qt4-dev-tools  4:4.8.5+git1 amd64        Qt 4 development tools
ii  qt4-doc        4:4.8.5+git1 all          Qt 4 API documentation
ii  qt4-linguist-t 4:4.8.5+git1 amd64        Qt 4 Linguist tools
ii  qt4-qmake      4:4.8.5+git1 amd64        Qt 4 qmake Makefile generator too
ii  qtchooser      39-g4717841- amd64        Wrapper to select between Qt deve
ii  qtcore4-l10n   4:4.8.5+git1 all          Qt 4 core module translations
ii  qtdeclarative5 0.4+14.04.20 amd64        Expose the Online Accounts API to
ii  qtdeclarative5 5.2.1-3ubunt amd64        Qt 5 Dialogs QML plugin
ii  qtdeclarative5 5.2.1-3ubunt amd64        Qt 5 localstorage QML plugin
ii  qtdeclarative5 5.2.1-3ubunt amd64        Qt 5 Private Widgets QML plugin
ii  qtdeclarative5 5.0~git20130 amd64        Qt Feedback module - QML plugin
ii  qtdeclarative5 5.2.1-3ubunt amd64        Qt 5 Qt Quick 2 QML plugin
ii  qtdeclarative5 0.23+14.04.2 amd64        Ubuntu web browser QML plugin
ii  qtdeclarative5 0.23+14.04.2 all          Ubuntu web browser QML plugin ass
ii  qtdeclarative5 0.1.46+14.04 amd64        Qt Components for Ubuntu - QML pl
ii  qtdeclarative5 1.1.0+14.04. amd64        Unity Action QML Components
ii  qtdeclarative5 5.2.1-3ubunt amd64        Qt 5 window QML plugin
ii  qthid-fcd-cont 4.1-3        amd64        Funcube Dongle controller
ii  rarian-compat  0.8.1-5ubunt amd64        Documentation meta-data library (
ii  readline-commo 6.3-4ubuntu2 all          GNU readline and history librarie
ii  remmina        1.0.0-4ubunt amd64        remote desktop client for GNOME d
ii  remmina-common 1.0.0-4ubunt all          common files for remmina remote d
ii  remmina-plugin 1.0.0-4ubunt amd64        RDP plugin for remmina remote des
ii  remmina-plugin 1.0.0-4ubunt amd64        VNC plugin for remmina remote des
ii  remote-login-s 1.0.0-0ubunt amd64        Service to track the remote serve
ii  resolvconf     1.69ubuntu1. all          name server information handler
ii  rfkill         0.5-1ubuntu1 amd64        tool for enabling and disabling w
ii  rhythmbox      3.0.2-0ubunt amd64        music player and organizer for GN
ii  rhythmbox-data 3.0.2-0ubunt all          data files for rhythmbox
ii  rhythmbox-mozi 3.0.2-0ubunt amd64        Rhythmbox Mozilla plugin
ii  rhythmbox-plug 3.0.2-0ubunt amd64        burning plugin for rhythmbox musi
ii  rhythmbox-plug 3.0.2-0ubunt amd64        Magnatune plugin for rhythmbox mu
ii  rhythmbox-plug 3.0.2-0ubunt all          zeitgeist plugin for rhythmbox mu
ii  rhythmbox-plug 3.0.2-0ubunt amd64        plugins for rhythmbox music playe
ii  rsync          3.1.0-2ubunt amd64        fast, versatile, remote (and loca
ii  rsyslog        7.4.4-1ubunt amd64        reliable system and kernel loggin
ii  rtkit          0.10-3       amd64        Realtime Policy and Watchdog Daem
ii  ruby           1:1.9.3.4    all          Interpreter of object-oriented sc
ii  ruby1.9.1      1.9.3.484-2u amd64        Interpreter of object-oriented sc
ii  samba-common   2:4.1.6+dfsg all          common files used by both the Sam
ii  samba-common-b 2:4.1.6+dfsg amd64        Samba common files used by both t
ii  samba-libs:amd 2:4.1.6+dfsg amd64        Samba core libraries
ii  sane-utils     1.0.23-3ubun amd64        API library for scanners -- utili
ii  sdcc           3.3.0+dfsg-1 amd64        Small Device C Compiler
ii  sdcc-doc       3.3.0+dfsg-1 all          Small Device C Compiler (document
ii  sdcc-libraries 3.3.0+dfsg-1 all          Small Device C Compiler (librarie
ii  seahorse       3.10.2-0ubun amd64        GNOME front end for GnuPG
ii  sed            4.2.2-4ubunt amd64        The GNU sed stream editor
ii  sensible-utils 0.0.9        all          Utilities for sensible alternativ
ii  session-migrat 0.2.1        amd64        Tool to migrate in user session s
ii  sgml-base      1.26+nmu4ubu all          SGML infrastructure and SGML cata
ii  sgml-data      2.0.9-1      all          common SGML and XML data
ii  shared-desktop 0.11.0-1     all          shared ontologies for semantic se
ii  shared-mime-in 1.2-0ubuntu3 amd64        FreeDesktop.org shared MIME datab
ii  shotwell       0.18.0-0ubun amd64        digital photo organizer
ii  shotwell-commo 0.18.0-0ubun all          digital photo organizer - common 
ii  signon-keyring 0.6+14.04.20 amd64        GNOME keyring extension for signo
ii  signon-plugin- 0.19+14.04.2 amd64        Single Signon oauth2 plugin
ii  signon-plugin- 8.56+14.04.2 amd64        Plain Password plugin for Single 
ii  signon-ui      0.16+14.04.2 amd64        Single Sign-on UI
ii  signond        8.56+14.04.2 amd64        Single Sign On framework
ii  simple-scan    3.12.1-0ubun amd64        Simple Scanning Utility
ii  sip-dev        4.15.5-1buil amd64        Python/C++ bindings generator cod
ii  smbclient      2:4.1.6+dfsg amd64        command-line SMB/CIFS clients for
ii  sni-qt:amd64   0.2.6-0ubunt amd64        indicator support for Qt
ii  software-cente 13.10-0ubunt all          Utility for browsing, installing,
ii  software-cente 0.1.6build1  all          The aptdaemon plugins for softwar
ii  software-prope 0.92.37.2    all          manage the repositories that you 
ii  software-prope 0.92.37.2    all          manage the repositories that you 
ii  soprano-daemon 2.9.4+dfsg1- amd64        daemon for the Soprano RDF framew
ii  sound-theme-fr 0.8-1        all          freedesktop.org sound theme
ii  speech-dispatc 0.8-5ubuntu1 amd64        Common interface to speech synthe
ii  speech-dispatc 0.8-5ubuntu1 amd64        Speech Dispatcher: Audio output p
ii  sphinx-voxforg 0.1.1~daily2 all          English sphinx acoustic model bui
ii  sphinx-voxforg 0.1.1~daily2 all          English sphinx language model bui
ii  ssh-askpass-gn 1:6.6p1-2ubu amd64        interactive X program to prompt u
ii  ssl-cert       1.0.33       all          simple debconf wrapper for OpenSS
ii  strace         4.8-1ubuntu5 amd64        A system call tracer
ii  sudo           1.8.9p5-1ubu amd64        Provide limited super user privil
ii  swig           2.0.11-1ubun amd64        Generate scripting interfaces to 
ii  swig2.0        2.0.11-1ubun amd64        Generate scripting interfaces to 
ii  synaptic       0.81.1ubuntu amd64        Graphical package manager
ii  syslinux       3:4.05+dfsg- amd64        collection of boot loaders
ii  syslinux-commo 3:4.05+dfsg- all          collection of boot loaders (commo
ii  syslinux-legac 2:3.63+dfsg- amd64        Bootloader for Linux/i386 using M
```

why this list don,t show any package which start previous alphabet of p ? i want to see all of my installed packages.

Comment: unclear for me. Could you explain your question?

Comment: question is edited. i think now the question is clear to you.

Comment: what happens if you enter `dpkg -l | more`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have so many packages that the whole list does not fit on your screen.
Use a pager like `less` and you can scroll the whole output: `dpkg -l|less`

Comment: Assuming Jan is correct, you can also increase the number of lines you can scroll back up in your terminal. If using gnome-terminal, you can do this from Edit -> Preferences -> Scrolling.

Comment: i am using Ubuntu 14.04 and scroll don,t up. because it starts at p for the command  '' dpkg -l ''. jan,s method is worked. i want to see the package which names start  e.thanks

Comment: Jan how do i  see the package already installed  which names start with E ?thanks

Comment: This is another question :-), anyway it's `dpkg -l "e*"`